# In terms of Prions is there a possibility, that other proteins apart from PRPC could be misfolded

Tags: pathology, infection, protein-folding, infectious-diseases, prion

This is as from research PRPC seems to be the cause of all Prion related diseases. Thank you

Comment: Can you please provide citations for your claim? Use the [edit] function to modify your post.

Comment: Please write a question as a question. A title is a title not a question. Take care to make clear the context of your problem and the research you have done to answer it yourself. Currently that is lacking.

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! Please take the [tour] and then go through the [help] pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site and [edit] your question accordingly. Please start by clarifying if you are only interested in human disease. In addition, we expect you to do some research on your own and then, informed by what you have learned, ask any questions you still have (ideally with references to reliable sources). See also this sites criteria for ["homework"](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/homework), which can even apply to questions not assigned as homework. Thanks! 

Answer (score 1):

There are many prions other than PrP; it is often helpful to e.g. read wikipedia for these cases.

For example, there are many yeast prions that are not homologous to PrP https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fungal_prion.

But even in humans there are a number of other proteins that form amyloids and are described as "prion-like" even though they aren't the canonical protein: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prion#In_other_diseases